# Display a trailing empty line in a code block

Tags: restructuredtext

I want to get an empty line at the end of a displayed code block.

This source as an example:

```
Some code block::

    Foo {
    }


Following text.
```

I want the resulting code block to be as so:

```
Foo {
}
<an empty line>
```

Despite all my efforts, the empty line is always removed from the result.

I can't accept any kind of CSS hack, i.e. if the user copies the code block, he should have the empty line in his clipboard.

Comment: Could you show the HTML you want?